# Subset a multisample VCF file

Tags: vcf, quality-control, gatk

I need some help with GATK. I have a multisample vcf file containing 18125 samples. After performing PCA I have around 303 samples as outliers and I wanted to remove these samples from my multisample vcf file.

I tried doing it using the GATK `SelectVariant` tool. It does some stuff and generates a VCF file which is a bit smaller in size than the original file, but in the end the total count of samples remains the same. As I have no prior knowledge of GATK (working with it for the first time) I am just wondering if you guys can help me out in fixing this issue.

The command that I used was

```
gatk SelectVariants -V filtered.vcf -xl-sn remove.txt -O test.vcf
```

`remove.txt` contains the sample names in each row (1 sample per row).

After running this command it generated a `test.vcf` file, for which I counted samples using:

```
bcftools query -l test.vcf | wc -l
```

However, I got exactly same number of samples as in the original VCF file `filtered.vcf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the way you've called the command (using `-xl-sn`), I assume you are using GATK 4 and not GATK 3.

If this is the case, the documentation for the `-xl-sn` flag is available here: https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/current/org_broadinstitute_hellbender_tools_walkers_variantutils_SelectVariants.php#--exclude-sample-name.

By default, the `-xl-sn SAMPLE` means "exclude the sample called SAMPLE from my VCF". In your case, you're providing an entire list of samples, in a file, which is not the default behaviour. In order to tell GATK that you're providing a file and not a sample name, **you need to ensure the file you provide has the extension `.args`**.

From the documentation:

> File names must use the extension ".args"

Comment: ok cool it worked thanks mate (Y)